# c++ Base Class Undefined C2504

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class CConfigButton which inherits from CCommandButton. I'm getting a base class undefined error on line 12 (inheriting CCommandButton).

Error Code:

```
Error   C2504   'CCommandButton': base class undefined  14
```

ConfigButton.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef CONFIG_BUTTON_H
#define CONFIG_BUTTON_H

class CConfigButton;

#include "Resource.h"
#include "CommandButton.h"



class CConfigButton :
   public CCommandButton {
public:
   //----- ButtonDefinitionSink
   STDMETHOD(ButtonDefinitionEvents_OnExecute) (NameValueMap *pContext);

};

#endif // !CONFIG_BUTTON_H
```

CommandButton.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef COMMAND_BUTTON_H
#define COMMAND_BUTTON_H



#include "Resource.h"
#include "swentylFRCAddinAddInServer.h"

class ATL_NO_VTABLE CCommandButton;

//class CCommandButton;
// CCommandButton

class ATL_NO_VTABLE CCommandButton :
   public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
   public IDispEventImpl<0, CCommandButton, &DIID_ButtonDefinitionSink, &LIBID_Inventor, 1, 0>
{

protected:
   //Inventor application object
   CComPtr<Application> m_pApplication;

   //Command button definition
   CComPtr<ButtonDefinitionObject> m_pCommandButtonDef;

public:
   CCommandButton()
   {
      m_pApplication = NULL;
      m_pCommandButtonDef = NULL;
   }

   DECLARE_NO_REGISTRY()

   BEGIN_COM_MAP(CCommandButton)
   END_COM_MAP()

   BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CCommandButton)
      SINK_ENTRY_EX(0, DIID_ButtonDefinitionSink, ButtonDefinitionSink_OnExecuteMeth, ButtonDefinitionEvents_OnExecute)
   END_SINK_MAP()

public:
   //----- ButtonDefinitionSink
   STDMETHOD(ButtonDefinitionEvents_OnExecute) (NameValueMap *pContext) = 0;

   HRESULT CreateButtonDefinition(Application* pApplication,
      BSTR bstrDisplayName,
      BSTR bstrInternalName,
      CommandTypesEnum eCommandType,
      VARIANT varClientId,
      BSTR bstrDescription,
      BSTR bstrToolTip,
      int StandardIconResId,
      int LargeIconResId,
      ButtonDisplayEnum eButtonDisplayType,
      ButtonDefinitionObject** pCommandButtonDefinition);

   HRESULT GetButtonDefinition(ButtonDefinitionObject** pCommandButtonDef);

   HRESULT Disconnect();
};

#endif // !COMMAND_BUTTON_H
```

I've searched for other similar problems, but haven't been able to find a solution. Others suggest a circular dependency is one possible source to the problem, but I don't believe I've done this. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do a preprocessor only compile step, and look at the intermediate source output.

Comment: Why do you have pragma once *and* header guards?

Comment: "I don't believe I've done this". Can you make sure? What is in Resource.h? Also, is it the only error that you get?

Comment: @Eljay I added #pragma message("Defined classname") to the header files and got this output: 1>  CommandButton.cpp
1>  Command Button Defined
1>  Config Button Defined

Comment: @Borgleader I just added the header guards when I was looking for other solutions to the problem

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé Resource.h gives the objects for Inventor (this is an addin that uses the autodesk Inventor developertools)

Comment: @TylerSwenson And do you get any other error messages? Anything from CommandButton.h?

Comment: Step one: make a [mcve].

Comment: @Borgleader I do that too.

Comment: What is `ATL_NO_VTABLE`? I'm unfamiliar with it and, consequently, the syntax you're using to declare your classes. My best guess it's a macro, but, if so, what is its value?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then I have the same question, why? Is there an advantage to having both of them that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Borgleader `#pragma once` may be a bit faster so it's good to have, but since it's inherently non-portable the header guards are a good fallback (plus they fix potential issues with hardlinks/symlinks)